# Having trouble clicking a link with selenium webdriver/java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to click the link below:

```
 <td id="mainleftlinkzoneover" class="mainleftlinks" width="151" title="Student Medicaid  Eligibility">
```

Here's the code. It works with other links like this but not this one.

```
        WebElement myElement = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 30))
              .until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("td[title='Student Medicaid  Eligibility']")));
        myElement.click();
```

Anyone have any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Why it's not working?? Is there any exception throwing or something else??

Answer (score 0):

you can do it by using the below code:

```
By.id("mainleftlinkzoneover") //here only id is used
```

or

```
By.cssSelector("#mainleftlinkzoneover[title='Student Medicaid  Eligibility']") // this is another way to locate element
```

use the any one instead of your By.cssSelector.

Make sure there are no frame.

Comment: That won't work because there are about ten such links and they all have that tag, the only thing I have to go on is the link text.

Comment: yup... if there are more than one element, than u have to use an unique locator , i update my answer ... use this and let me know if it works or what error it shows

Comment: That's not working either. No matter what I try I just can't get this to work.

Comment: so what error it gives you? and if u use #mainleftlinkzoneover[title='Student Medicaid  Eligibility'] in ur website manually, how many count it gives you?

Answer (score 0):

Is the link available for others to check? I mean can I test it if I want? you can give the url if possible.

here are my 2 cents:

I am thinking because of the spaces in your title, you might not be able to click on it. 
I would try using contains
something like  By.xpath("//td[contains(@title,'Eligibility')]") you can put either student or medicaid if they are unique. See if that helps.